# textual description inside html number field

Tags: html, input, numbers, field

Is it possible to have text in number field which describes the value?

For example:

5 Year(s)

6 Year(s)
...

A number field Years. We have number inside the input, we can increase and decrease the number inside the input using arrows and after the number we have description 'Years'

Answer (score 0):

No, Just put it as a label after and if you need that text when you submit the form you can put it in a hidden field, create a function to find the value of your label or is it a static value?

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat vague, but I suppose this is more or less what you are asking for:

```
 <input type=number id=years name=years> <label for=years>years</label>
```